# Managed workflow Expo 38 - java.lang.NullPointerException on Android in production

Tags: android, react-native, expo

As the title says, the app throws a null exception in production on Android. Using the Expo 38 SDK.

This is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException:
at com.facebook.react.ReactRootView.setAllowImmediateUIOperationExecution (ReactRootView.java:480)
at com.facebook.react.ReactRootView.onMeasure (ReactRootView.java:130)
at android.view.View.measure (View.java:24730)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6858)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:194)
at android.view.View.measure (View.java:24730)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6858)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:194)
at android.view.View.measure (View.java:24730)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6858)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:194)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure (ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
at android.view.View.measure (View.java:24730)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6858)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout (LinearLayout.java:1552)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical (LinearLayout.java:842)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure (LinearLayout.java:721)
at android.view.View.measure (View.java:24730)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6858)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:194)
at android.view.View.measure (View.java:24730)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6858)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout (LinearLayout.java:1552)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical (LinearLayout.java:842)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure (LinearLayout.java:721)
at android.view.View.measure (View.java:24730)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6858)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:194)
at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure (DecorView.java:749)
at android.view.View.measure (View.java:24730)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure (ViewRootImpl.java:3264)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy (ViewRootImpl.java:2047)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals (ViewRootImpl.java:2342)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal (ViewRootImpl.java:1935)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run (ViewRootImpl.java:8023)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:1163)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:986)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:902)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:1148)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:883)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:100)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7695)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:516)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

Btw, on a related note, how do you debug this? How to map the Java code in production, to the JS code? I’m looking at Sentry right now, but it seems they don’t support native crash reports either.